# Cannot get parent in angular component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to provide my own parent component to NgModel as dependency.
As i understood from [NgModel source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) it requires instance of `ControlContainer` from parent. If i wrap `<input ngModel name="foo">` into form `NgModel` gets instance of this form. So i decided to create my own directive `MyForm` which also extends `ControlContainer`, but when i wrap input with element with MyForm on it NgModel receives null.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9JhXoePXPePgfLUaOu7R?p=preview)

Comment: it doesn't work this way

Comment: Thanks for great answer, @RomanC.. Just in case someone interested in - you have provider on directive with `{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyForm) }`. In this case when NgModel asks for ControlContainer angular DI system will give instance of this directive.